# Pygame events not responding with time.time()

Tags: python-2.7, time, pygame

Using Python 2.7.11, the `time.time()` function is causing trouble with pygame. I have functions for checking pygame events and responding to them.

```python
def check_keydowns(event):
    global points
    """ Checks the key that has been pressed """
    global running
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        print "Hi"
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        running = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        points += 1


def check_keyups(event):
    global points
    """ Checks the key that has been released """
    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        print "Bye"
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        points += 1


def check_events():
    """ Check the type of event from the user """
    global running
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydowns(event)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyups(event)
```

My main problem is that `time.time()` doesn't seem to respond to `time.time() - t0 == 1`.

```python
t0 = time.time()
# The main loop for the game
while running:

    update(GRAY, x, y, points)  # Updates the text and redraws the screen
    check_events()  # Checks key presses

    if time.time() - t0 == 1:
        points += 1
        t0 = time.time()
```

I want the text on the screen to increase by 1 every second. But the problem is the variable `points` stays at zero (that is how the variable is initialized - any other number `points` doesn't change. Also, the `points` variable is an `int`. I also tried printing the value of `points` but, again, 0 is the output.

I don't understand python that well so please try to simplify the answer (and an explanation would be nice) as much as possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using very detailed float numbers, subtracting them and expecting it to be equal to an int.

This is virtually impossible.

Instead use a simple inequality to check if 1 second has passed.

```
t0 = time.time()
# The main loop for the game
while running:

    update(GRAY, x, y, points)  # Updates the text and redraws the screen
    check_events()  # Checks key presses

    if time.time() - t0 > 1:
        points += 1
        t0 = time.time()
```

Instead of checking if the two float numbers equal exactly 1 when subtracted. Just check if the difference is greater than 1.

I hope this answer helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below.

Comment: I used your idea on this solution works great. I also understand your reasoning why my previous choice didn't work. This has been very helpful.

Comment: Thank you! Glad I could help ;D